# asmx wsdl loading forever

Tags: asp.net, iis, wsdl, asmx

I have a web service application which has suddenly stopped working.  I have enabled directory browsing in IIS, and can view the application directory.  I can view the xml files within the application directory, but I cannot view the .config files, nor can I view the wsdls of any of the web services.  When I try to browse to `http://server/app/service.asmx?wsdl`, the browser stays in the "loading" state forever.

Any ideas what might have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in the server's event log? Many ASP.NET errors will end up there, this sounds like it might qualify

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question about loading, are you able to browse to the site on the server?

IIS protects Web.config files by default and will typically return a "This type of page is not served" error message. This is a good thing which will keep your connection strings and what not from being casually viewed. There is more information about allowing exceptions for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431233/cassini-error-this-type-of-page-is-not-served).